# How can I make the OS treat a Network drive as local?

Tags: networking

I am kinda new to linux, so forgive me for being rather useless with linux. I am trying to configure my media PC with linux instead of windows since windows kept crashing.
Anyway, I have downloaded qBittorrent and have been trying to get it to import torrent files and download to my 8TB NAS. I have mapped the drive however qBittorrent seems to only want local drives. Hence I want to try and make linux treat them like they are local so that qBittorrent can make use of them.

I have attached screenshots.

Any help is much welcome!

[image: Here you can see the File Browser, I have mounted the public folder and also bookmarked the network fold "downloaded torrents"]

[image: This is what the qBittorrent file browser looks like, my network drive does not show up]

Answer (score 2):

[Try this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13366/mounted-windows-network-folders-do-not-show-in-open-save-box-on-native-apps/14165#14165)

I had the same kind of issue before. Many applications do not see the mounted drives so you have to make a folder link that will then look like a local folder. I would have added this as a comment but I need a higher reputation it seems. I take no credit for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/) shows you how to do it in Ubuntu 14.04 (Elementary Loki is based on 16.04) but it should work for you.